# Vaadin Table columns autosize/autoscale without horizontal scrollbar

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin table, with say 5 columns.
In the last column (right-most) we have the edit/delete buttons which always take up the same amount of width.

When I set the width of the last column to a specific width, and all other columns to a specific `setColumnExpandRation(10);` then everything is ok, with the exception that the normal columns are not autoscaled.

When I the the last column to a specific width, and all other columns to autoscale, (`setColumnWidht(-1)`), then the normal columns are sized depending the content, but the whole table width is too large and shows a horizontal scrollbar.

Example of such a case in the picture below

[image: Wrong width]

And the java code:

```
    Table tb= new Table();
    tb.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    tb.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    layout.addComponent(tb);

    BeanItemContainer<Person> pList =
        new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class);
    for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Person p1= new Person("******", "++++++++++", "--++--++--++--++--++--++", "????", "3333 "+i, new Date());
        pList.addBean(p1);
    }

    tb.setContainerDataSource(pList);
    tb.setColumnWidth("zip", 20);
    tb.setColumnExpandRatio("firstName", 1);
```

[image: Example of code above]

Is there a way to have the last column with a fixed width, but still have the other columns auto sized, to have widths depending the content?

Comment: What do you mean with sentence: "normal columns are not autoscaled". What are normal columns? Columns with expand ratio 10?

Comment: I understand, you mean columns which are not generated columns.

Comment: a minimal code example is always helpful get a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set table to be 100% width.
Then to set last column to have fixed widht.

Set the only one of the other columns to have expand ratio 1, to force other columns to get proper space.

Container which contains table must have 100% width.

If you get scrollbars then you must wrap text inside table.

Comment: I don't wish to wrap the text inside the table, one line of text is OK, even when part of the text is cut off at the column end

Comment: Did you try this solution and what is the result. Do you get scrollbars again?

Comment: I did add a small example to the question. The h-scrollbar is shown instead of making the columns smaller

Comment: In this situation you can set expand ratio on all columns or wrap text inside table. If you dont want to wrap text you will always have a scroll bar because of calculating column width based on content.

Comment: The vaadin6 table did not need such work arrounds... http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#TableColumnAlignment :(

Comment: In that example, notice that on column which has Country names expand ratio is 1 table.setColumnExpandRatio(ExampleUtil.iso3166_PROPERTY_NAME, 1);